# Conditional Formatting using R A G for Dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Want to use R A G so if date in cell is after todays date the cell turns red, Amber if within 3 months of expiry and green if more than 3 months from expiry.

I have tried using a basic formulae, but getting nowhere with this, can anybody please help, thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

So like this:

[image]

3 conditional formatting rules based on today().

Note I had the column A selected from the start to end date when setting the formula in the conditional formatting, also note the relative addressing for A3.